# Can Windows issue a warning when you try to close an application?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, I use an application which I sometimes close by accident. Is there a way to make Windows issue a "Do you really want to do this" warning when I try to close the application? (It's just a normal Windows application which I usually close by clicking the cross in the upper right corner of the window.)

Comment: This can only be handled by the program's author.

Comment: In my experience programs prompt me if something is unsaved, and that is always my biggest worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly using windows,  but you could use this small donation ware program to turn off the Close button on windows.

http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose

You can still close the program using the File>Exit option if it has one and you would need to add it to your start up to work all the time.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the close button on a normal window, the operating system sends a "window message" to the process that owns that window; for example, `WM_CLOSE` ([technical info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Windows provides a built-in API (part of the Win32 API) which you can use to intercept window messages sent to other windows, even out-of-process. So you could write an external application that does this.

See [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) routine.